# How to web structure?

Tags: http-status-code-404

i have 6 web sites, mydomain.com this is my first web site, directory is public_html and other 5 is in public_html/domain.com
I didn't recognize it will work like mydomain.com/domain.com. 
The main problem is a link deis twice. for example:
domain.com/index.php&option... if this link dies
mydomain.com/domain.com/index.php&option... dies too. I want to fix it. Is there any way to rewrite the directions. Example:
mydomain.com/domain.com/index.php&option... -> domain.com/index.php&option... etc

Answer (score 1):

these are called `virtual hosts`.  you need to search for how to configure virtual hosts.  you need to search for instructions specific to the web server you are using (IIS, Apache, etc).